# dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding-automacilly adds new line?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, line-breaks

```
NSData *data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

test is a random string

Is NSData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding adding a line break after the string automatically?

Im a beginner and i need to get rid of the line break. I send the data via BLE to a device. But its restricted to 20 bytes and I've to separate my string in two or three parts. But the break line leads to errors.

Comment: sry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are breaking the large string into smaller string and than sending the data. This might be the main problem due to which new line is added. You can try this

> before converting the string into data make sure no whiteline character are added. Thus, you need to trim the white spaces for all the substrings you make.

Try this

```
[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

also if you want to specifically remove newline character then try this

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

Hope this will help you, Happy Coding :)

Comment: ty for your reply. Now i´m sure that my receiver device is the reason why the break line is appended.@Shubhendu

Comment: @mond did my answer helped you in figuring the problem?